# Add paho mqtt cpp library in CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, mqtt

Following the instructions on their github repo I managed to build and install both libraries
`paho-mqtt-c` and `paho-mqtt-cpp`

in a custom directory
`C:\mqtt\paho-c`
`C:\mqtt\paho-cpp`

Now I'm trying to add those libraries in my project. My `CMakelists.txt` is as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

enable_language(CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:/mqtt/paho-cpp/lib/cmake/PahoMqttCpp)
find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)

project(mqtt_test)

add_executable(mqtt_test main.cpp)
```

However, cmake insists on asking me where to find them.

`Could NOT find PahoMqttC (missing: PAHO_MQTT_C_LIBRARIES PAHO_MQTT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS)`

Why do I need to tell `cmake` again where to find C libraries? I think that was the job of `find_package` to also include those variables because I set it up on building and installation time.

Operating system: Windows 11 x64.
cmake version: 3.22.2
cmake generator: Ninja
C compiler: 11.2.0 (cygwin64)
C++ compiler: 11.2.0 (cygwin64)

EDIT: I manually specified the paths

```
set(PAHO_MQTT_C_LIBRARIES C:/mqtt/paho-c/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a-static.a)
set(PAHO_MQTT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS C:/mqtt/paho-c/include)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:/mqtt/paho-cpp/lib/cmake/PahoMqttCpp)
find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)
```

However I'm getting a compilation error:

```
fatal error: mqtt/async_client.h: No such file or directory
61 | #include "mqtt/async_client.h"
```

I know how to solve it by manually adding the include paths in my cmakelist but I'm trying to figure out how to use their cmake module properly. `find_package` doesn't seem to do that.
Or I'm missing something.

Comment: Try adding the mqtt project to the dependency list of the mqtt_test project (i.e. use `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`)

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko Thanks! That solved the problem

Comment: avoid using directly TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES. That's prompt to the list corruption. Better use  target_link_libraries() method which adds to the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES list whatever you prompt it with.
Also, TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES is not a dependency list, it is a list of libraries that must be link to a TARGET, either library or executable. The collateral of doing this is that cmake caches all the PATHS related to that library added to this list.

Comment: @MrBit Could you please include how you solved the problem? Great question btw, going through the same myself right now.

Comment: Had the same problem on linux. The solution was not to add the `cmake` dir to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` but the common parent dir that hosts the `include`, `lib` etcetera dirs. Probably in your case: `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/mqtt/paho-cpp")`. Then the quirks of manually adding hardcoded dirs where unnecessary. You can then add the found include dir: `include_directories(${PAHO_MQTT_C_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. As you still need to link to the library, you will have to add `target_link_libraries(mqtt_test PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3-static)`  as well or without `-static`, for dynamic linkage.